# Background task sometime fails on simulator / Always fails on device

Tags: ios

I'm starting a background task in -applicationDidEnterBackground that uploads data to my server, if the user has changed settings relevant to the push notifications. When the user changes a setting I set a static BOOL to YES and only send the changes when the app enters the background. I pass the a block ending the task to the method so when reaching connectionDidFinishLoading it calls it and ends the task.

It works most the times on the simulator, but doesn't work on the actual device.

Relevant code:

```
self.bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^
 {
     [application endBackgroundTask:self.bgTask];
     self.bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
 }];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^
   {
       [PushInfo checkDirty:^{
           NSLog(@"push info sent");
           [application endBackgroundTask:self.bgTask];
           self.bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
       }];
   });
...
// in PushInfo.m :
typedef void (^VoidBlock)();
static BOOL dirty;

+ (void) checkDirty:(VoidBlock)endBlock
{
    if(dirty)
    {
        PushInfo *pi = [[PushInfo alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"sending pushinfo");             // This code is always reached
        [pi setEndBlock:endBlock];
        [pi updatePushInfo];
    }
    else
        endBlock();
}

- (void) updatePushInfo
{
   ...
   // Create a NSURLConnection to send the data
   ...
}

- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
  ...
  NSLog(@"sent push info");
  dirty = NO;
  if(endBlock)
  {
    endBlock();
  }
}
```

Am I missing anything ?
EDIT : even when it does send the information to the server on the simulator, the static variable is still YES for some reason...

Comment: when you say it doesn't work on the device, do you mean it never reaches inside the dispatch_async block? Also what device are you testing on?

Comment: I've stepped through it and it reaches all the way to where I create the NSURLConnection. After that I can't step through the code neither on the simulator nor the device. I'm using an iPhone 4s with iOS 5.1 and an iOS 6 simulator.( haven't tested on the 5.1 sim yet)

Comment: as a side-note, since i started testing the background task, the Springboard is always scrolled a bit to the left, and I can see a bit of the icon of my app on the other page. o.O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended using +sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:

Answer (score 1):

<del>Try moving your code to:</del>

<del>-(void) applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application</del>

<del>I believe having it in applicationDidEnterBackground is too late.</del>

Checked the docs, and you are right, it should be fine in applicationDidEnterBackground.

Another suggestion, try moving beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler inside the dispatch_async block. It *may* have to be started in the same thread but didn't see this explicitly stated in the documentation.

Comment: the apple docs do it in appdidenterbackground. anyway, will try your suggestion. tomorrow. gotta go home now :)

Comment: tried moving the bbeginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler inside the dispatch_async, but that didn't work at all. ended using  +sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error: since it has nothing to do with the ui thread anyway.